# Does Exchange have the capability to run macros/vba like Outlook does?

Tags: vba, exchange-server, attachment, rules

We have a macro and rule set up in Outlook that does the following:

Rule:

If the incoming mail is TO: a certain address run thru the following macro:

Macro:

1) Reply to sender with the original message, with canned text inserted before message, and any attachments stripped out.

2) Forward the original message, to a set of email addresses, placing some text on the subject line (in addition to original subject line) and stripping any attachments.

This works fine via the Outlook client, as long as the client is open.

We need to know if this sort of functionality is available within Exchange (current version).

Does Exchange have the ability to  run the same sort of rule and macro on incoming mail for this one account?

Our Exchange admins are not seasoned Exchange admins, and we do not have access to Exchange to find out for ourselves. We want to be able to tell them matter-of-factly if it can be done or not, as they want to bill us to even find out if it is a built-in feature or not.

Not looking for how to do it but if it can/cannot be done with default Exchange, and possibly where to find the capability.

Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see here for an example:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324021

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help! Now to make it happen with the info provided!

Comment: This MS Support URL seems to be broken.